# Objective-C popup does not position

Tags: ios, objective-c, transformation

I have a large bitmap in Xcode, on which a popup (UIView) is placed. Per default, it's hidden and is visible when pressing a button.
When visible, a x/y position is set... and it works.

After positioning, I want the popup appear with a scale-effect. This also works; however, the x/y positioning is ignored and the popup just appears where it's positioned in the Storyboard editor.

```
// Set position
    minPopupFrame.origin.x = (_destinationensKoordinater[0] - minPopupFrame.size.width/2 + offsetX) * zoomfaktor;
    minPopupFrame.origin.y = (_destinationensKoordinater[1] - minPopupFrame.size.height + offsetY) * zoomfaktor;
    _popup.frame = minPopupFrame;
    // Scale it to .1
    _popup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.1, .1);
    _popup.hidden = NO;

    // Set size to 100% in .3 seconds
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    _popup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

It's quite basic coding - but why doesn't it work? Suggestions, pretty please?

EDIT: I've also tried something like this - but the code is completely ignored:

```
_popup.hidden = NO;
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200, 200);
    CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
    _popup.transform = transform;
```

EDIT II: I also tried this:

```
_popup.center = CGPointMake((_destinationensKoordinater[0] - minPopupFrame.size.width/2 + offsetX) * zoomfaktor, (_destinationensKoordinater[1] - minPopupFrame.size.height + offsetY) * zoomfaktor);
_popup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.1, .1);
_popup.alpha = 0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
_popup.alpha = 1;
_popup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The interesting bit is that the alpha animation works, but the popup positioning is ignored, if the first _popup.transform line isn't commented out. It doesn't make sense to me

Comment: You probably forgot to connect the outlet, check whether `_popup` is null. Also, you should use the property rather than the instance variable directly.

Comment: Hmm, no - that's not it. The outlet is named _popup by the way. The variable minPopupFrame is equal to _popup.frame.

Comment: I've discovered something odd - please see the edited code in the bottom of the question